# actionscript 3.0 generating random numbers and storing them in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm creating a Plinko type game and need to generate a random number -- either a 0 or a 1 -- 136 times and store it in an array of 136 elements. In other words, the value of each of the 136 elements will either be the integer 0, or the integer 1, randomly chosen.
The following code randomly produces a 0 or a 1, 136 times:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 136; i++) {

var randNum:Number = Math.floor (Math.random()*2);

}

trace(randNum);
```

Hence, I have the the first portion of the code done. What I don't know how to do is the second part: storing the 136 integers (0 or 1) in an array.
The following video gives an example of how to perform such a task in C++ :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0PqC2HCkL8

But I'm new to all this and don't know how to write such a function for ActionScript 3.0.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: [If tutorials for C++ are available, why wouldn't there be ones for AS3?](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html) or [Alternative](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1, so you can simply use Math.round(arg) to get an integer.

```
const numbers: Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
for (var i: int = 0; i < 136; i++) {
    numbers.push(Math.round(Math.random()));
}
```

Comment: const numbers: Array = new Array();
       
   for (var i: int = 0; i < 136; i++) {
   
   numbers.push(Math.round(Math.random()));
    
    
   }
    
   trace (numbers);
   trace (numbers.length);
   trace (numbers[0]);

Answer (score 0):

That worked great, thanks. I substituted Array for Vector. The trace output shows it to be working perfectly.

```
        var numbers: Array = new Array();
        for (var i: int = 0; i < 136; i++) {
        numbers.push(Math.round(Math.random()));
        }
        trace (numbers);
        trace (numbers.length);
        trace (numbers[0]);
```